# Vertical align middle and centered text on top of image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the text over an image using vertical aligned middle and text align center. But none of them seems working.

My html is

```
<div class="hero-image">
  <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png" alt="">
  <a href=""><h2>Some Sample text</h2></a>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/zkno1sc2/

Is it because I am not specifying the width of the image in parent div?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the `.hero-image` in combination with `align-items: center;`:

```css
.hero-image {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
.hero-image img{
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-image h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png" alt="">
  <a href=""><h2>Some Sample text</h2></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the "top" padding, See the code:

```css
.hero-image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-image a {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 45%;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/ahcg75tsb/hero.png" alt="">
  <a href=""><h2>Some Sample text</h2></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top-image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.top-image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.centered-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-image-container">
    <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/529/529895.jpg" alt="Top Image" />
    <div class="centered-text">Centered Text</div>
</div>
<div>
<p>---Any Content here---</p>
<p>The text is centered vertically and horizontally in an image.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).